Ошибка: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-12-15T23:57:53.875+01:00 ERROR 6112 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataBuilderInitializer: Provider org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteMetadataBuilderInitializer could not be instantiated
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:288) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:970) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1361) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1350) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at com.service.auth_service.AuthServiceApplication.main(AuthServiceApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataBuilderInitializer: Provider org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteMetadataBuilderInitializer could not be instantiated
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:809) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:725) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.collectServiceIfNotDuplicate(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.loadAll(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.getAll(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:241) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:419) ~[spring-orm-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:400) ~[spring-orm-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1849) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1798) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/dialect/function/SQLFunction
    at org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteMetadataBuilderInitializer.(SQLiteMetadataBuilderInitializer.java:29) ~[sqlite-dialect-0.1.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1160) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.ensureClassInitialized(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:340) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.newConstructorAccessor(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.acquireConstructorAccessor(Constructor.java:549) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:785) ~[na:na]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
    ... 41 common frames omitted

Мой Maven:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.service</groupId>
<artifactId>auth-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>auth-service</name>
<description>auth-service</description>
<url/>
<licenses>
    <license/>
</licenses>
<developers>
    <developer/>
</developers>
<scm>
    <connection/>
    <developerConnection/>
    <tag/>
    <url/>
</scm>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0.Final</version> <!-- Используйте версию Hibernate 6.x -->
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.gwenn</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.36.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

База создается и существует, проверено:
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class DatabaseSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:/D:/Diplom/microservApp/auth-service/src/main/java/DB/database.db"; // Путь к файлу базы данных
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl)) {
            // Создание таблицы для пользователя
            String createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user ("
                    + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + "username TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + "password TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + "role TEXT NOT NULL);";

            // Выполнение SQL запроса на создание таблицы
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
                statement.executeUpdate(createTableSQL);
            }

            // Добавление пользователя 'USER' с паролем и ролью
            String insertUserSQL = "INSERT INTO user (username, password, role) VALUES "
                    + "('USER', 'password', 'USER');"; // Создайте реальный пароль для пользователя
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
                statement.executeUpdate(insertUserSQL);
            }

            // Извлечение и вывод данных о пользователе
            String selectUserSQL = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = 'USER';";
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectUserSQL)) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    // Получение данных о пользователе и вывод на экран
                    int id = rs.getInt("id");
                    String username = rs.getString("username");
                    String password = rs.getString("password");
                    String role = rs.getString("role");
                    System.out.println("User created: ");
                    System.out.println("ID: " + id);
                    System.out.println("Username: " + username);
                    System.out.println("Password: " + password);
                    System.out.println("Role: " + role);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Database and user created successfully.");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Database creation failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

application.properties:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:/D:/Diplom/microservApp/auth-service/src/main/java/DB/database.db
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false


Hibernate 6.x НЕ содержит кода для интерфейса org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction, вероятно, следовало использовать более раннюю версию Hibernate 5.x, который мог бы использоваться совместно с устаревшей версией диалекта для SQLite 0.1.1 от 1 декабря 2020 г.

См. ответ на EngSO, на подобный вопрос, если нужно всё же использовать SQLite с Hibernate 6.

В Hibernate 6, SQLite является частью Диалектов Сообщества:

Одна из областей, в которой мы действительно зависим от сообщества, — это поддержка диалектов сообщества в репозитории Hibernate. Модуль диалектов сообщества определяет совместимость с рядом старых баз данных, включая Informix, Ingres и Teradata, а также инкубирует поддержку SQLite. Эти диалекты не поддерживаются командой Hibernate, поскольку у нас нет возможности их протестировать.
Существует множество способов улучшить или расширить эти диалекты. В частности, в них обычно отсутствует поддержка расширенных или более новых функций HQL. Так что если у вас есть доступ к одной из этих баз данных, мы будем рады, если вы сможете нам помочь!


Поэтому, для установки соответствующего диалекта SQLite, нужно использовать следующие зависимости:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

